# Datatable Javascript shows horizontal scroller bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Can you please help?

```
   <table id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr/>
                    </thead>
<tbody/>
                </table> 



    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "oScroller": {
        serverWait: true
    },
    "bInfo": true,
    "aaSorting": [
        [1, 'asc']
    ], // Default first column sort
    "sDom": 'tiS',
```

The table keeps resizing itself while scrolling

Comment: how is your html table ? post more code..

Comment: are u setting the datatable to table id `myTable` or `Classtable` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think that your table structure are roung according to datatable, try creating a table like this:

```
<table class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Res 1</td>
            <td>Res 2</td>
            <td>Res 3</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

if you want, you cant set a  `<tfoot>`

try this and se if works, set the `$("#example").dataTable({...});`.